# eclipse plugin objectaid install failed

Tags: objectaid

I'd like to make some class diagrams from source code and want to install objectaid which is an eclipse plugin that helps to generate UML diagram.

```
Help->Install new software->add->http://www.objectaid.net/update
```

It stucked on 48% and displayed "fetching ..." and several hours later it showed the following errors

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.bridge_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.dom_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.dom.svg_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.ext.awt_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.extension_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/features/org.apache.batik_1.6.0.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.parser_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.pdf_1.6.0.v201105071520.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.svggen_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.swing_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.transcoder_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.apache.batik.xml_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
Connection timed out: connect
Unable to connect to repository http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar
Connection timed out: connect
```

There is a firewall and I had used goagent to cross the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like a network issue. I used the same repository url and I was able to successfully install ObjectAid inside eclipse. Do checkout the [step](http://evverythingatonce.blogspot.in/2016/04/tech-talk-reverse-uml-generator-in.html), I have compiled it with a screenshot - in case you are missing anything.